# .callFake with $q still doesn't enter .then block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I've written a couple of these tests previously on other controllers and it works just fine. But on this more complex controller, no matter which function I test it on, the `.callFake` using `$q` is not entering into the `.then` block and so no logic in there is being executed at all. I know the controller works for sure as this is on a production website. So why doesn't my test even enter the `.then` block when I've returned the deferred promise?

Controller Code -

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('EntryAddController', EntryAddController);

  function EntryAddController($scope, $state, moment, $sanitize, EntryFactory, $modal, toastr, $log) {
    var vm = this;
    var now = moment();
    var $currentYear = now.year();

    vm.queues = [];
    vm.calculating = false;
    vm.total = 0;

    vm.saving = false;
    vm.addTxt = 'Confirm Entry';

    var tomorrow = now.add(1, 'days').toDate();
    var to = now.subtract(1, 'days').add(12, 'months').toDate();

    vm.fromDate = tomorrow;
    vm.toDate = to;

    activate();

    ////////////////

    function activate() {

      var queueCache = {};

      vm.updateEntrys = function() {

          var payload = {
            'from': moment(vm.fromDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
            'to': moment(vm.toDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
            'freq': vm.frequency.value,
            'total': vm.total_amount
          };

          var key = JSON.stringify(payload);

          if (!(key in queueCache)) {

            EntryFactory.getEntryQueue(payload)
              .then(function(resp) {

                //LOGIC HERE BUT TEST NEVER ENTERS HERE DESPITE USING $Q
              });

          } else {

            vm.queues = queueCache[key].queue;
            vm.total = queueCache[key].total;
            vm.calculating = false;
          }
      }
    } 
  }
})();
```

Test Code

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('Entry Add Controller Spec', function(){

    var vm;
    var $controller;
    var $q;
    var $rootScope;
    var EntryFactory;
    var $scope;
    var toastr;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _EntryFactory_) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      $q = _$q_;
      EntryFactory = _EntryFactory_;

      vm = $controller('EntryAddController', { $scope: $scope });
    }));

    it('expect EntryFactory.getEntryQueue to correctly set queues and total upon successful response', function() {
      var payload = "blah";
      var resp = {
        "data": 1
      }

      spyOn(EntryFactory, 'getEntryQueue').and.callFake(function(payload) {     
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(resp);
        return deferred.promise;
      });

      EntryFactory.getEntryQueue(payload);

      $rootScope.$apply();

      //expect logic in .then to have worked

    });
  });
})();
```

**Edit**

Just thought of something... is this because I'm calling the factory function (`EntryFactory.getEntryQueue`) directly in the test, instead of calling the `vm.updateEntrys` function around it and therefore it doesn't ever proceed onto the `.then` portion of the code?

Comment: There is no `.then` block in your test. The `.then` block is in the `vm.updateEntrys` method which you are not calling, so what `.then` block are you expecting to execute? Also, side note: the way you're creating that promise is ugly. You can replace all of that with `return $q.resolve(resp);`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was taught to create promises that way via multiple online tutorials, didn't know there's a better/cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allways need to consider what your SUT (System/Software under test) is.
In this case it is a controller's component method vm.updateEntrys.
It calls your Mocked EntryFactory.getEntryQueue() method. Also your code is not complete (where do you define vm.frequency object?). Nevertheless I have tested this method with the following test :

```
    /*property
    $apply, $log, $modal, $new, $sanitize, $scope, $state, EntryFactory, and,
    callFake, data, defer, getEntryQueue, moment, promise, resolve, toastr,
    updateEntrys
*/
(function () {
    'use strict';

describe('Entry Add Controller Spec', function () {

    var vm;
    var $controller;
    var $q;
    var $rootScope;
    var EntryFactory;
    var $scope;
    var toastr;

    beforeEach(module('app.controllers'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $q = _$q_;

    }));

    beforeEach(function () {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        EntryFactory = {
            getEntryQueue: function () {

            }
        };

        moment = function () {
            return {
                format: function () {

                }
            }
        }

        vm = $controller('EntryAddController', { '$scope': $scope, '$state': {}, 'moment': moment, '$sanitize': {}, 'EntryFactory': EntryFactory, '$modal': {}, 'toastr': {}, '$log': {} });
    });

    it('expect EntryFactory.getEntryQueue to correctly set queues and total upon successful response', function () {
        var payload = "blah";
        var resp = {
            "data": 1
        };

        spyOn(EntryFactory, 'getEntryQueue').and.callFake(function (payload) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(resp);
            return deferred.promise;
        });

        vm.updateEntrys();

        EntryFactory.getEntryQueue(payload);

        $scope.$apply();

        //expect logic in .then to have worked
    });
});
```

})();

Comment: Thank you!! Clarifies a lot.